# How to get the elements count inside nested elements in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, nested, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the count of each li element inside ul element (dynamic), tried multiple ways but end up with getting wrong count..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9jem.png)

```
const ctrlElement = await page.$$('#resources > li');
for(let i=0; i<ctrlElement.length; i++){
    const controllerName = await ctrlElement[i].$eval('div[class=heading] > h2 > a', ctrlName => ctrlName.innerText) // giving correct text
    const liCount = await ctrlElement[i].$eval('ul > li'); // Not giving expected count 
    console.log(liCount.length) // Not giving expected count
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the wrong number? Is ctrlElement.length the same as the number of li elements under the `#resources` element?

Comment: @Anshu are you getting the correct value for ctrlElement

Comment: I'm getting the correct value for ctrlElement @theFrontEndDev

Comment: @bluejayke ctrlElement.length is populating correctly, inside it ul is there under it there is N number of li, I need this count, which is populating wrong

Comment: Instead of console logging console.log(liCount.length) why not console.log(liCount)

Comment: When I debug I got to know that It's giving count from #resouces> div>ul>li path, but I want from #resources> ul>li this path

Comment: @bluejayke  console.log(liCount) this won't give you count

Answer (score 0):

Got the sol:

```
const li_count = await ctrlElement[i].$$('ul[class=endpoints]>li',liCount => liCount); // This returns JSHandle@node list
console.log('content of li:'+li_count ); // It prints num of JSHandle@node
console.log('lenght of li:'+li_count.length); // Gives the actual count under li
```